# get second dimension of the array using std::extent

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the second dimension of a 2D array using `std::extent`, but getting output as `0`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


int32_t main(int32_t argc, char *argv[]) {
    int32_t arr[10][100];
    
    std::cout << "first dim: " << sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "second dim: " << sizeof(*arr) / sizeof(**arr) << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "rank: " << std::rank<decltype(arr)>{} << std::endl;
    std::cout << "first dim: " << std::extent<decltype(arr)>{} << std::endl;
    std::cout << "second dim: " << std::extent<decltype(*arr)>{} << std::endl;
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? Which version of it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `gcc 9.2`

Comment: That should have pretty good support for the type-traits and `decltype`. So the only explanation I can think about is that `arr` and `*arr` decays to pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the second dimension use this:

```
std::cout << "second dim: " << std::extent<decltype(arr),1>{} << std::endl; 
                                                   //    ^ second dimension !
```

Comment: I have to admit that I don't understand why the original doesn't work. Just thought this is better an answer than a comment

Comment: It probably doesn't work because `decltype(*arr)` does something they don't expect. This is the proper way to do it and, of course, [is documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent).

Comment: @underscore_d not doing what I expect isnt really the problem. Also when I inspect what `decltype(*arr)` resolves to I dont get it https://godbolt.org/z/6qYd16 Is it not an array type with 100 elements along its first dimension?

Comment: @idclev463035818 This is very interesting. `decltype(*arr)` *is* an array type, so `extent` should work fine. Have you figured this out yet? If not, I'll post a question, since OP seems fine with the just the fix.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Ok, I figured it out, and posted an answer :)

Answer (score 6):

The reason you get the result of `0` is that `decltype(*arr)` has type `int32_t(&)[100]`, which is a *reference* to an array type. `std::extent` returns `0` unless you pass it *exactly* an array type.

You can get the expected result by removing the reference like this:

```
std::extent<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*arr)>>{}  // 100
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rss9dr).

Comment: compilers that support only c++11 standard can use `std::extent<std::remove_reference<decltype(*arr)>::type>{}`